# Inserting a tag in between xml using C++

Tags: c++, xml

I have a xml inside which I wish to insert the tag using insert() of string class.

Here is my xml:

```
< ? xml version="1.0" ? >
< Dependency_Structure >
   < Main_Package >
      < Package_Name >
         WinTools
      < /Package_Name >
      < Header_File >
         WinTools.h
      < /Header_File >
      < Implementation_File >
         WinTools.cpp
      < /Implementation_File >
   < /Main_Package >
   < Dependencies >
      < Dependency_Package >
         wintools
      < /Dependency_Package >
   < /Dependencies >
< /Dependency_Structure >
```

Here is my function code which is aborting the execution of the program whenever I try to execute it:

```
std::string line,str;

std::fstream myfile(xmlFileName, ios::out | ios::in);
//myfile.open()
 if(myfile.is_open())
 {
        getline(myfile,line);
        size_t pos=line.find("</Dependency_Package >");
        line.insert(pos,fileInput);

 }
 else
    std::cout<<"Unable to open the file. "<<endl;
myfile.close();
```

Comment: How about using [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/0)

Comment: What happens if you don't find the word you are looking for? Like if the file contains several lines of text?

Comment: Then I have written a separate code for that where I will add the tag... but that's a complete different code of implementation. Here is where I am wishing to add a string in a file.

Comment: There was bit typing mistake. I am willing to add the string after the </Dependency_Package> and this closing tag would always be present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, you are not testing the result of the find to see if the position is greater or equal to zero.  Second, if you are going to insert and save back to the file, you are closing the file before the insert.

Comment: I can include a check... but the tag is always going to be present in the xml. Also, I have printed the value of "pos" on console and it came out to be greater than 0. I am closing the file after the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake here is trying to write to *line* instead of writing to the file itself.

*line* is the string you just read. This is how you could write to the file:

```
// Move the write cursor where read cursor is currently located 
// (or wherever you want it to be)
myfile.seekp(myfile.tellg());
myfile << "<CheckThisTag>\n\t YEAH BABY\n<\\CheckThisTag>\n";
```

Comment: Don't forget to move the rest of the content forward, because writing to a specific position on the file will overwrite whatever is already there. Ideally, you could have 2 files for this task: one just to read from, and the other to write to!

Comment: Hey Karl, this didn't work out for me. Wasn't able to move the rest of the contents forward and hence its overriding my whole file lot many times. But anyways I implemented the requirements using different other operations I had implemented. All the help provided is MUCH APPRECIATED!!! Thanks :)